# jQuery plugin overriding the url in default settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Hey here i'm creating a jquery plugin which have default settings as

```
var settings = {
        renderTo:'body',
        width: 800,
        height:900,
        url:'miserables.json',
        zoom:true,
        loadingText:"loading...",
        margin:{
                    top: -5,
                    right: -5,
                    bottom: -5,
                    left: -5
                }
    };
```

So when i overwrite  this settings as

```
$(function(){
$('#diagram').renderSvg({
    renderTo: '#diagram', // THIS IS WORKING
    height:500, // THIS IS WORKING
    width:200, // THIS IS WORKING
    url:'check.json' //THIS IS NOT WORKING INSTEAD OF I'M GETTING DEFAULT URL
});
```

});

so how can override the url. please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: you will have to show us the complete plugin,,,

Comment: Assuming `check.json` is a file, try providing a more specific path to the file, such as `/check.json`

Comment: i tried but not getting. In console i'm getting  'miserables.json'.

Comment: width , height every thing is working fine but cant able to override the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you extend default option with custom settings. For this, move `settings` intialization into `renderData` function and call it from `renderSvg` like:

```
this.renderData(options);
```

So the code will become:

```
$.fn.renderData = function (options) {

    var options = $.extend({}, {
        renderTo: 'body',
        width: 800,
        height: 900,
        url: 'miserables.json',
        zoom: true,
        loadingText: "loading...",
        margin: {
            top: -5,
            right: -5,
            bottom: -5,
            left: -5
        }
    }, options);

    console.log(options.url);

    // ...
};
```

and

```
 $.fn.renderSvg = function (options) {
     this.renderData(options);
     // ...
 };
```

Comment: Remove all `var settings = ` stuff, you only need  `var options = $.extend({}, {` in `renderData`.